# Object Animator clipping the viewgroup

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am creating an animation by translating a viewgroup in Y direction from its original position to top.

I am facing a weird issue in Android 13. The view group is getting clipped when moving the viewgroup to top. I have checked the same in a phone running Android 10, it is working fine.

I am attaching a screen recording of both phones.

[image: Behaviour in android 13]

[image: Behaviour in android 10]

Here the code from animation.

```
        val totalAnimationDuration = 2000L

        val context = cameraUIBinding!!.stepsLayout.context

        val moveOutAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            cameraUIBinding!!.stepsLayout,
            "translationY",
            -context.dpToPx(200f)
        )
            .apply {
                duration = totalAnimationDuration
                interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
                repeatCount = 5
            }

        moveOutAnimator.start()
```

Here is the android studio layout screenshot.

[image: Android Studio Layout]

Answer (score 0):

Set these to all the parent `ConstraintLayout` and its parent ViewGroups too:

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false"
```

Or you can try increasing the elevation of your `stepsLayout` a bit so it overlap other views:

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

Comment: I have already tried this before. didn't work either.

Comment: I think you can try to move your `stepsLayout` outside of the `ConstraintLayout`, a `FrameLayout` as the parent is still better for translation